# How to add Glow Effect Flex 3 Chart?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, charts, effects

I created a custom component in Flex 3 that contains a column chart. I also added code that will allow the user to drill down on a column when there is underlying detail data. If there is no data, clicking on the column has no effect.

I want to make the column under the mouse glow when the drill down functionality is possible as a visual signal to the user.

How do I make the column glow when my IF statement results in true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding. `filters="{(isPossible) ? [glow] : []}"` -- that should update whenever isPossible changes.